# 'After update' event firing when node is deleted

Tags: rules

I have a rule set up that uses the following action:

> After updating existing content of type

It's working fine when a node is updated, but I just discovered that this rule also fires when nodes of the specified type are deleted. This makes sense, since changing the status of a node is technically an update, but this is not the desired effect as emails should not be sent when the node is deleted.

I added a small chunk of PHP inside the email generated by the rule to see what the value of $node->status is in this rule, but it is still 1, not 0 as I expected.

How can I use the '`After updating existing content of type`' event, but not have it react when a node of that type is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a rules condition for the published status of the updated node? That should stop the rule from firing.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it will react on node deletion also, as I had tested it.

'After updating existing content of type' event it will use [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), so it will never trigger [hook_node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)

Have a look on any other Rules overriding that.

Comment: Taking about "testing it": me too (so I agree)! Have a look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227517/39516) for an extremely basic rule I created for my testing ... PS: sorry I cannot +1 your answer anymore ... (I already did).